# git: BUG: read-cache.c:327: unsupported ce_mode: 40000

Tags: git, coredump

When calling `git commit -m "XXX"` I am getting this error:

```
BUG: read-cache.c:327: unsupported ce_mode: 40000
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is there any way to get out of this situation, e.g. by deleting some cached files?

Answer (score 1):

This message means that somehow, a directory got added to Git's index, which is not typically expected or allowed.  The "BUG" portion of the message means that this should never happen, and you'd want to report it to the Git mailing list [as outlined here], possibly by using `git bugreport`.

You could try doing `git update-index -q --really-refresh` to see if you can reload the data on disk.  You may want to back up `.git/index` for later debugging first, though.